Keeping Login Bar on the Header in Wix Studio
I am currently making a new website that requires the 'customer' to create and account/login. I have been having trouble with the login bar. The login bar is on the right hand of the screen. It shows the customers display name and their notifications. If the customers name is too long, the bar will strech to the right and go outside of the visibility area. I wanted it to strech and move to the left so it always stays in the same spot and doesn't go outside of the visibility area.
I tried moving the login bar around, but that just made it dumb luck (If the customers name was the perfect length, it would fit, if it was too long it would go outside of the visibility area, if it was too short, it just looked weird.)
Perfect fit:

Streching outside of visibility area:

